# No additional drivers available; though they were available when I tried Ubuntu!

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-gnome, additional-drivers

I used to use (before 2.5 years) Ubuntu 14.04 in my Desktop PC and then shifted to Trisquel GNU/Linux-Libre as mentioned in my profile. Recently I've purchased Dell Laptop (which has 2GB of Nvidia Graphics card) and there is Windows 10 installed. As I like GNOME more than Unity, I've recently downloaded Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.02 LTS.

After creating bootable USB stick of it, I've first used "Try Ubuntu" option to get the idea of how is it. When I checked Additional Drivers, it was showing two available drivers 1. Wireless network (wifi I think) and 2. Nvidia Graphics. I've just installed that Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.02 LTS but now Additional Drivers is saying "no additional drivers available"!

I don't understand why is installed system is not listing those drivers shown in demo version (I mean try now copy). Do I have to manually install wifi & graphics driver or is there any way to detect automatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh! that was because I disabled/unchecked restricted repository which provides proprietary drivers. I just checked/enabled it again and after reloading packages, I can now see both drivers available:

[image]

This may be useful for others if they face similar issue otherwise I'm not sure whether question can be closed as off-topic (This describes a problem that can't be reproduced that seemingly went away on its own or was only relevant to a very specific period of time. It's off-topic as it's unlikely to help future readers.)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, what I did was go to software & updates (icon with a box and an earth). Clicked on Ubuntu Software tab, unchecked Proprietary drivers for devices, then rechecked. I clicked on REVERT. Clicked on Additional drivers. It performed an update, then then they appeared. This worked for me.

Comment: If proprietary drivers option is already checked then simply `sudo apt update` should work.